# why dont display relation data in Rest Yii2

Tags: php, rest, yii, yii2, yii-rest

why dont display relation data in Rest Yii2

i have two tables.

sample:
category , subcategory

```
    <?php

namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\Category;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\rest\Controller;

class ApiController extends Controller
{

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['contentNegotiator']['formats'] = ['application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON];
        return $behaviors;
    }

    public function actionGetSk($cId)
    {
        $result= Category::find()->with('subCategory')->where(['id' => $cId])->all()

        return $result;
    }
}
```

i result i have only from Category. (result is json)

but print_r($result) i have data from Category and subCategory.

web.php

```
[
'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
'pluralize' => false,
'controller' => 'api',
],
```

Comment: Post your controller declaration and attributes

Comment: @gmc How to Post??

Comment: I meant that you should add that code to what you have already posted, editing you question

Comment: @gmc edited. how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Try this: in your `Category` model, add this method:

```
public function extraFields() {
        return [
            'subcategory' => 'subCategory',
        ];
    }
```

And now, call your api with the `expand` get parameter like:

```
http://yourapi.com/api/get-sk?cID=1&expand=subcategory
```

Comment: return $result is json result but in JSON only category result but in print_r($result) i have category , subcategory. why?